# Elegancy/Succinct script-writing

Tags: python, html

I'm fairly fresh to the world of python and feel as though I'm overcomplicating the script that I have produced, is there any way it could be simplified or any techniques that could be incorporated that I'm unaware of? (Apologies if this is overly vague)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, urllib2, re
es="http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=protein&term="+sys.argv[1]
ef="http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id="
url=urllib2.urlopen(es)
match=url.readlines()
print "<head>"
print "<style>"
print "table, th, td {"
print "    border: 1px solid black;"
print "}"
print "</style>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<table>"
print "<tr>"
print "<th>GI number</th>"
print "<th>ID</th>"
print "<th>Nucleotide sequence</th>"
print "</tr>"
for line in match:
  col1=re.search(r'<Id>(.*)</Id>',line)
  if col1:
    fetch=ef+col1.group(1)+"&rettype=fasta&retmode=xml"
    urlf=urllib2.urlopen(fetch)
    print "<tr>"
    print "<th>"
    print "<a href=\"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/"+col1.group(1)+"\">"+col1.group(1)
    print "</a>"
    print "</th>"
    pline="".join(urlf.readlines())
    col2=re.search(r'<TSeq_sequence>(.*)</TSeq_sequence>',pline)
    col3=re.search(r'<TSeq_defline>(.*)</TSeq_defline>',pline)
    if col3:
      print "<td>"
      print col3.group(1)
      print "</td>"
      ltot=(len(col2.group(1))/40)+1
      ln=0
      print "<td>"
      while ln<=ltot:
        bnd1=ln*40
        bnd2=(ln+1)*40
        print col2.group(1)[bnd1:bnd2]
    ln+=1
    print "</tr>"   
print "</body>"
print "</table>"
```

Comment: Yes, templates for strings.

Comment: Indentation is not correct.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Check out Jinja. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/intro/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a print line for every single line of html code, you can create large chunks of code using multi-line strings, eg:

```
topSection = """<head>
  <style>
  table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>GI number</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nucleotide sequence</th>
    </tr>"""
```

For sections of html code that require some values to be programatically inserted you can use the format string method, eg:

```
variable1 = "some value"
variable2 = "some other value"
htmlsection = """<HTML CODE>
<MORE HTML CODE>
<MORE HTML CODE>
<HTML CODE WITH A VARIABLE VALUE = {0}>
<HTML CODE WITH ANOTHER VARIABLE VALUE = {0}>""".format(variable1, variable2)
```

You can then concatenate all of the string components and just use one single print statement:

```
print(topSection + middleSection + endSection)
```